# javascript to get the value of a div if it has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="home">

<div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
```

Each of this div has forms in it which has a hidden field  `<input type="hidden" name="selectedRadioValue" id="selectedRadioValue">`

So I would like to create a javascript which would assign a value to the hidden input field.

```
if($("#home").hasClass("active"))                               //Dont know whether this is  
                                                            // true
    {
      assign "radio1" as the value in the input hidden field //what could be the equvalent                                     
                                                             //  statement for this?
    }
else if($("#profile").hasClass("active"))
    {
     assign "radio2" as the value in the input hidden field  //what could be the equvalent                                     
                                                             //  statement for this?
    }
```

Im sorry for this kind of a question.Im new to javascript,so I have tried a little bit of statements myself,but I need help.How to accomplish this?Please help

Solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        if ($("#home").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio1');
        } else if ($("#profile").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.selectedRadioValue').val('radio2');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: document.forms[0].selectedRadioValue = "radio2";

Comment: `#` is the id selector prefix. So `$('#home')` and `$('#profile')`

Comment: Please read up on selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: actually there are two form in both the divs,which has the same hidden field,so this value will be assigned to both the hiddenfield right?

Comment: What is the purpose of the hidden field, and selecting it? It seems like what you are doing is way more than you really need to do, just trying to get a handle on what your working towards, and might be able to steer you in a different direction.

Comment: Kelly,thanks for the response.Actually this divs are tabs in my html.So when I select a div,active class is added to it.So depending on which tab/(where the active class is),I want to assign a value to the input field present in forms in this divs.When I post the form,I should get the "value" of which tab was active when posting the form.Thats what I need

Comment: You can't have two input fields with `id="selectedRadioValue"`. IDs are required to be unique.

Comment: oh,then what can I do ,if I need to assign to two fields at same time?Can I use its name?

Comment: You can use the name, or you can give them a class.

Comment: so the name cal be selected like $("#selectedRadioValue").val("radio2"); if selectedRadioValue is the name of both the fields?

Comment: You don't need to add `[solved]` to your question. Accepting an answer serves that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through every tab pane that is active, then select form that is in that tab pane and then get hidden value in that form. Then set value that you get to radio button in that same form.

Also, it's not good to have multiple elements with same id like `#selectedRadioValue`. Consider using classes instead.

```
$(function() {
    // Loop through all active tab panes
    $('.tab-pane.active').each(function() {
        // Get hidden input value
        var hiddenValue = $('form #selectedRadioValue', $(this)).val();

        // Set radio input value to hidden input value
        // Radio inputs should have '.radio-input' class tho
        $('form .radio-input', $(this)).val(hiddenValue);
    });
});
```

### Edit

Ohh, you need to assign hidden inputs to radio1/radio2? Then your code is correct and all you need to do is assign radio1/radio2 as the value of your input. Just add class like `radio-hidden` to it and then do `$('.radio-hidden').val('radio1');` etc.

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        if ($("#home").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.radio-hidden').val('radio1');
        } else if ($("#profile").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.radio-hidden').val('radio2');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3NAC9/

Comment: See radio1 and radio2 is just the values.Its not anything related to radio buttons in html

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#home").hasClass("active"))                              
{
  $("#selectedRadioValue").val("radio1");
}
else if($("#profile").hasClass("active"))
{
   $("#selectedRadioValue").val("radio2");
}
```

Should do what you want I think?

Answer (score 0):

Change the hidden input fields to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedRadioValue" class="selectedRadioValue">
```

Then your JS could be:

```
var radio_map = {
    'home': 'radio1',
    'profile': 'radio2'
};
$('.selectedRadioValue').val(radio_map[$(".tab-pane.active").attr('id')]);
```

Here's how it works:

- `$(".tab-pane.active")` selects the active `tab-pane` element.
- `.attr('id')` gets that element's ID
- `radio_map[id]` gets the value in `radio_map` corresponding to the given ID.
- `$(.selectedRadioValue')` selects all the hidden inputs with that class.
- `$(.selectedRadioValue').val(...)` sets all their values.

Comment: can you tell me how this works?The last statement  $('.selectedRadioValue').val(radio_map[$(".tab-pane.active").attr('id')]);
  what does this do?

Comment: Updated the answer with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you.Your is working expect that,when I change the tab,it doesnt trigger the change.When the page loads,the active class is in 'home'.But when I change the tab,the javascript doesnt run.The scrip runs only at the time of page loading

Comment: You need to run this code in an event handler that reacts to changes. Javascript doesn't automatically re-run code unless you tell it to.